# Complete crash and log is unhelpful

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios14

I've encountered a crash on my personnal device after a few minutes using it, and I have absolutely no clue how to debug it or even understand the issue.

Note that the crash log didn't get send to crashlytics and even though I reported it via the iPhone's prompt, it doesn't show up in Xcode organizer either.

I managed to grab the log by hooking by phone to my laptop, but now I really don't know how to read this, so any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Right now the only thing that seems interesting to me is the increase in footprint `Footprint: 79.16 MB -> 526.83 MB (+447.67 MB)`, so maybe the OS decided to kill the app?

```
Date/Time:        2021-02-01 17:44:21.819 +0100
End time:         2021-02-01 17:48:45.141 +0100
OS Version:       iPhone OS 14.3 (Build 18C66)
Architecture:     arm64e
Report Version:   32
Incident Identifier: 5B9CAD2A-654F-4227-86E8-F6169797DD78
Share With Devs:  Yes

Data Source:      Microstackshots
Shared Cache:     5EA4CDF9-15E1-39F8-A027-6308C347603D slid base address 0x1984c0000, slide 0x184c0000

Command:          APP NAME
Path:             /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F738A7F8-37FE-403F-B614-3406087E7B25/APP NAME.app/APP NAME
Identifier:       com.domain.app
Version:          1.18.1 (1.18.1)
Adam ID:          1510911574
Is First Party:   No
Is Beta:          Yes
Cohort:           2|date=1611439200000&sf=143442&tid=c0ef7542eda47a034bca0e770f4f7512615d0c61749502a7197f8fdf831bdd2d&ttype=i
Beta Identifier:  35ED2D27-DD4D-4E84-9FD0-DBACD34E58A8
PID:              95978

Event:            wakeups
Action taken:     none
Wakeups:          45001 wakeups over the last 263 seconds (171 wakeups per second average), exceeding limit of 150 wakeups per second over 300 seconds
Wakeups limit:    45000
Limit duration:   300s
Wakeups caused:   45001
Wakeups duration: 263s
Duration:         263.32s
Duration Sampled: 229.74s
Steps:            29

Hardware model:   iPhone12,1
Active cpus:      6


Heaviest stack for the target process:
  10  ??? (libsystem_pthread.dylib + 14280) [0x1e40e77c8]
  10  ??? (libdispatch.dylib + 86304) [0x19851b120]
  9  ??? (libdispatch.dylib + 84284) [0x19851a93c]
  8  ??? (libdispatch.dylib + 101384) [0x19851ec08]
  8  ??? (libdispatch.dylib + 28972) [0x19850d12c]
  8  ??? (libdispatch.dylib + 15792) [0x198509db0]
  6  ??? (CoreFoundation + 636708) [0x19888b724]
  6  ??? (libsystem_kernel.dylib + 17104) [0x1c66682d0]


Powerstats for:   APP NAME [95978]
UUID:             5BD8C77A-45E5-3F20-B64B-E49D0B172C10
Adam ID:          1510911574
Is First Party:   No
Is Beta:          Yes
Cohort:           2|date=1611439200000&sf=143442&tid=c0ef7542eda47a034bca0e770f4f7512615d0c61749502a7197f8fdf831bdd2d&ttype=i
Beta Identifier:  35ED2D27-DD4D-4E84-9FD0-DBACD34E58A8
App Version:      1.18.1
Build Version:    1.18.1
Path:             /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F738A7F8-37FE-403F-B614-3406087E7B25/APP NAME.app/APP NAME
Architecture:     arm64
Footprint:        79.16 MB -> 526.83 MB (+447.67 MB)
Pageins:          23 pages
Start time:       2021-02-01 17:44:51.927 +0100
End time:         2021-02-01 17:48:41.664 +0100
Num samples:      29 (100%)
Primary state:    10 samples Frontmost App, Non-Suppressed, User mode, Effective Thread QoS User Interactive, Requested Thread QoS User Interactive, Override Thread QoS Unspecified
User Activity:    0 samples Idle, 29 samples Active
Power Source:     29 samples on Battery, 0 samples on AC
  10  _pthread_wqthread + 215 (libsystem_pthread.dylib + 14280) [0x1e40e77c8]
    10  _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 115 (libdispatch.dylib + 86304) [0x19851b120]
      9   _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 355 (libdispatch.dylib + 84284) [0x19851a93c]
        8   _dispatch_source_invoke + 1259 (libdispatch.dylib + 101384) [0x19851ec08]
          8   _dispatch_continuation_pop + 415 (libdispatch.dylib + 28972) [0x19850d12c]
            8   _dispatch_client_callout + 19 (libdispatch.dylib + 15792) [0x198509db0]
              6   CFRunLoopWakeUp + 339 (CoreFoundation + 636708) [0x19888b724]
                6   mach_msg_trap + 8 (libsystem_kernel.dylib + 17104) [0x1c66682d0]
                  4   <Kernel mode, Requested Thread QoS Utility>
                  1   <Kernel mode, Effective Thread QoS Utility, Requested Thread QoS Utility>
                  1   <Requested Thread QoS Utility>
              1   CFRunLoopWakeUp + 423 (CoreFoundation + 636792) [0x19888b778]
                1   _pthread_mutex_firstfit_unlock_slow + 247 (libsystem_pthread.dylib + 28684) [0x1e40eb00c]
                  1   __psynch_mutexdrop + 8 (libsystem_kernel.dylib + 164312) [0x1c668c1d8]
                    1   <Kernel mode, Effective Thread QoS Utility, Requested Thread QoS Utility>
              1   CFRunLoopWakeUp + 115 (CoreFoundation + 636484) [0x19888b644]
                1   _CFGetNonObjCTypeID + 248 (CoreFoundation + 667180) [0x198892e2c]
                  1   <Effective Thread QoS Utility, Requested Thread QoS Utility>
        1   _dispatch_source_invoke + 1487 (libdispatch.dylib + 101612) [0x19851ecec]
          1   _dispatch_continuation_pop + 415 (libdispatch.dylib + 28972) [0x19850d12c]
            1   _dispatch_client_callout + 19 (libdispatch.dylib + 15792) [0x198509db0]
              1   _Block_release + 215 (libsystem_blocks.dylib + 6004) [0x1e407a774]
                1   objc_destructInstance + 95 (libobjc.A.dylib + 116816) [0x1ad89a850]
                  1   _object_remove_assocations + 115 (libobjc.A.dylib + 130056) [0x1ad89dc08]
                    1   bool objc::DenseMapBase<objc::DenseMap<DisguisedPtr<objc_object>, objc::DenseMap<void const*, objc::ObjcAssociation, objc::DenseMapValueInfo<objc::ObjcAssociation>, objc::DenseMapInfo<void const*>, objc::detail::DenseMapPair<void const*, objc::ObjcAssociation> >, objc::DenseMapValueInfo<objc::DenseMap<void const*, objc::ObjcAssociation, objc::DenseMapValueInfo<objc::ObjcAssociation>, objc::DenseMapInfo<void const*>, objc::detail::DenseMapPair<void const*, objc::ObjcAssociation> > >, objc::DenseMapInfo<DisguisedPtr<objc_object> >, objc::detail::DenseMapPair<DisguisedPtr<objc_object>, objc::DenseMap<void const*, objc::ObjcAssociation, objc::DenseMapValueInfo<objc::ObjcAssociation>, objc::DenseMapInfo<void const*>, objc::detail::DenseMapPair<void const*, objc::ObjcAssociation> > > >, DisguisedPtr<objc_object>, objc::DenseMap<void const*, objc::ObjcAssociation, objc::DenseMapValueInfo<objc::ObjcAssociation>, objc::DenseMapInfo<void const*>, objc::detail::DenseMapPair<void const*, objc::ObjcAssociation> >, objc::DenseMapValueInfo<objc::DenseMap<void const*, objc::ObjcAssociation, objc::DenseMapValueInfo<objc::ObjcAssociation>, objc::DenseMapInfo<void const*>, objc::detail::DenseMapPair<void const*, objc::ObjcAssociation> > >, objc::DenseMapInfo<DisguisedPtr<objc_object> >, objc::detail::DenseMapPair<DisguisedPtr<objc_object>, objc::DenseMap<void const*, objc::ObjcAssociation, objc::DenseMapValueInfo<objc::ObjcAssociation>, objc::DenseMapInfo<void const*>, objc::detail::DenseMapPair<void const*, objc::ObjcAssociation> > > >::LookupBucketFor<DisguisedPtr<objc_object> > const + 152 (libobjc.A.dylib + 128480) [0x1ad89d5e0]
                      1   <Effective Thread QoS Utility, Requested Thread QoS Utility>
      1   _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 287 (libdispatch.dylib + 84216) [0x19851a8f8]
        1   _dispatch_root_queue_poke_slow + 247 (libdispatch.dylib + 66020) [0x1985161e4]
          1   __workq_kernreturn + 8 (libsystem_kernel.dylib + 168324) [0x1c668d184]
            1   <Kernel mode, Effective Thread QoS Utility, Requested Thread QoS Utility>
  10  start + 3 (libdyld.dylib + 5808) [0x19854a6b0]
    10  ??? (APP NAME + 23620) [0x102441c44]
      10  UIApplicationMain + 167 (UIKitCore + 12380244) [0x19b2ce854]
        10  -[UIApplication _run] + 1071 (UIKitCore + 12357600) [0x19b2c8fe0]
          10  GSEventRunModal + 163 (GraphicsServices + 14212) [0x1b038e784]
            10  CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 599 (CoreFoundation + 631324) [0x19888a21c]
              4   __CFRunLoopRun + 2359 (CoreFoundation + 635020) [0x19888b08c]
                4   __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 595 (CoreFoundation + 660344) [0x198891378]
                  4   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 59 (CoreFoundation + 663528) [0x198891fe8]
                    4   __CFMachPortPerform + 175 (CoreFoundation + 511440) [0x19886cdd0]
                      4   display_timer_callback + 279 (QuartzCore + 974508) [0x19bcbeeac]
                        4   CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch_items + 663 (QuartzCore + 84456) [0x19bbe59e8]
                          4   @objc DisplayLink.displayLinkTimer + 43 (SwiftUI + 3834176) [0x19f220140]
                            4   DisplayLink.displayLinkTimer + 99 (SwiftUI + 3834072) [0x19f2200d8]
                              3   _UIHostingView.displayLinkTimer + 167 (SwiftUI + 11128108) [0x19f914d2c]
                                2   ViewRendererHost.render + 339 (SwiftUI + 9534676) [0x19f78fcd4]
                                  2   closure #1 in ViewRendererHost.render + 1443 (SwiftUI + 9571056) [0x19f798af0]
                                    2   ViewGraph.updateOutputs + 107 (SwiftUI + 4953012) [0x19f3313b4]
                                      2   GraphHost.runTransaction + 171 (SwiftUI + 10264244) [0x19f841eb4]
                                        1   AG::Subgraph::update + 796 (AttributeGraph + 61856) [0x1c1c0e1a0]
                                          1   <Kernel mode>
                                        1   AG::Subgraph::update + 464 (AttributeGraph + 61524) [0x1c1c0e054]
                                1   ___chkstk_darwin + 48 (libsystem_pthread.dylib + 42908) [0x1e40ee79c]
                              1   _UIHostingView.displayLinkTimer + 191 (SwiftUI + 11128132) [0x19f914d44]
                                1   CA::Transaction::commit + 731 (QuartzCore + 937780) [0x19bcb5f34]
                                  1   CA::Context::commit_transaction + 415 (QuartzCore + 760428) [0x19bc8aa6c]
                                    1   CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed + 143 (QuartzCore + 1524860) [0x19bd4547c]
                                      1   CA::Layer::layout_if_needed + 523 (QuartzCore + 1440904) [0x19bd30c88]
                                        1   -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 307 (QuartzCore + 1439668) [0x19bd307b4]
                                          1   -[UIView layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 999 (UIKitCore + 17914276) [0x19b8159a4]
                                            1   -[UIViewController _updateTraitsIfNecessary] + 247 (UIKitCore + 4864652) [0x19aba3a8c]
                                              1   -[UIViewController traitCollection] + 103 (UIKitCore + 4862632) [0x19aba32a8]
                                                1   -[UIPresentationController traitCollection] + 39 (UIKitCore + 3730844) [0x19aa8ed9c]
                                                  1   -[_UIRootPresentationController presentingWindow] + 0 (UIKitCore + 3756244) [0x19aa950d4]
              4   __CFRunLoopRun + 1055 (CoreFoundation + 633716) [0x19888ab74]
                4   __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 575 (CoreFoundation + 632260) [0x19888a5c4]
                  4   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 35 (CoreFoundation + 656216) [0x198890358]
                    4   @objc closure #1 in static NSRunLoop.addObserver + 55 (SwiftUI + 1866556) [0x19f03fb3c]
                      4   closure #1 in static NSRunLoop.addObserver + 63 (SwiftUI + 1866212) [0x19f03f9e4]
                        4   autoreleasepool<A> + 63 (libswiftObjectiveC.dylib + 7984) [0x1bec26f30]
                          4   specialized thunk for @callee_guaranteed -> (@error @owned Error) + 23 (SwiftUI + 1844564) [0x19f03a554]
                            4   closure #1 in closure #1 in static NSRunLoop.addObserver + 15 (SwiftUI + 1866244) [0x19f03fa04]
                              4   static NSRunLoop.flushObservers + 147 (SwiftUI + 1866400) [0x19f03faa0]
                                4   thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed -> () + 27 (SwiftUI + 5086500) [0x19f351d24]
                                  4   closure #1 in GraphHost.asyncTransaction<A>partial apply + 39 (SwiftUI + 10281700) [0x19f8462e4]
                                    4   closure #1 in GraphHost.init + 123 (SwiftUI + 10276612) [0x19f844f04]
                                      4   ViewGraphDelegate.updateGraph<A> + 79 (SwiftUI + 4943364) [0x19f32ee04]
                                        4   ViewRendererHost.updateViewGraph<A> + 91 (SwiftUI + 9533576) [0x19f78f888]
                                          4   closure #1 in ViewRendererHost.updateViewGraph<A> + 107 (SwiftUI + 9568492) [0x19f7980ec]
                                            4   partial apply for closure #1 in ViewGraphDelegate.updateGraph<A> + 27 (SwiftUI + 4958268) [0x19f33283c]
                                              4   closure #1 in closure #1 in GraphHost.asyncTransaction<A> + 23 (SwiftUI + 10276660) [0x19f844f34]
                                                4   GraphHost.flushTransactions + 175 (SwiftUI + 10271092) [0x19f843974]
                                                  4   GraphHost.runTransaction + 91 (SwiftUI + 10276764) [0x19f844f9c]
                                                    4   GraphHost.runTransaction + 171 (SwiftUI + 10264244) [0x19f841eb4]
                                                      4   AG::Subgraph::update + 883 (AttributeGraph + 61944) [0x1c1c0e1f8]
                                                        4   AG::Graph::update_attribute + 331 (AttributeGraph + 24564) [0x1c1c04ff4]
                                                          4   AG::Graph::UpdateStack::update + 491 (AttributeGraph + 23488) [0x1c1c04bc0]
                                                            2   partial apply for specialized implicit closure #2 in implicit closure #1 in closure #1 in closure #1 in Attribute.init<A> + 23 (SwiftUI + 3206604) [0x19f186dcc]
                                                              2   specialized DynamicContainerInfo.updateValue + 339 (SwiftUI + 2222368) [0x19f096920]
                                                                1   specialized DynamicContainerInfo.updateItems + 383 (SwiftUI + 2226640) [0x19f0979d0]
                                                                  1   ViewList.applySublists + 119 (SwiftUI + 9662400) [0x19f7aefc0]
                                                                    1   ViewList.applySublists + 67 (SwiftUI + 9669080) [0x19f7b09d8]
                                                                      1   protocol witness for ViewList.applyNodes in conformance ForEachList<A, B, C> + 59 (SwiftUI + 8784188) [0x19f6d893c]
                                                                        1   ForEachList.applyNodes + 39 (SwiftUI + 8783252) [0x19f6d8594]
                                                                          1   ForEachState.applyNodes + 51 (SwiftUI + 8769000) [0x19f6d4de8]
                                                                            1   ForEachState.forEachItem + 1395 (SwiftUI + 8762836) [0x19f6d35d4]
                                                                              1   closure #1 in ForEachState.applyNodes + 376 (SwiftUI + 8769392) [0x19f6d4f70]
                                                                1   specialized DynamicContainerInfo.updateItems + 67 (SwiftUI + 2226324) [0x19f097894]
                                                                  1   outlined init with copy of _ViewList_Elements + 0 (SwiftUI + 5135996) [0x19f35de7c]
                                                            1   partial apply for implicit closure #2 in implicit closure #1 in closure #1 in closure #1 in Attribute.init<A> + 31 (SwiftUI + 3785960) [0x19f2144e8]
                                                              1   StaticBody.updateValue + 231 (SwiftUI + 7090404) [0x19f53b0e4]
                                                                1   ViewBodyAccessor.updateBody + 1631 (SwiftUI + 3636956) [0x19f1efedc]
                                                                  1   withUnsafePointer<A, B> + 27 (libswiftCore.dylib + 1463284) [0x19c6683f4]
                                                                    1   partial apply for thunk for @callee_guaranteed -> (@error @owned Error) + 27 (SwiftUI + 3662164) [0x19f1f6154]
                                                                      1   AGGraphSetOutputValue + 635 (AttributeGraph + 121900) [0x1c1c1cc2c]
                                                                        1   assignWithCopy for ModifiedContent + 91 (SwiftUI + 3869160) [0x19f2289e8]
                                                                          1   assignWithCopy for ModifiedContent + 91 (SwiftUI + 3869160) [0x19f2289e8]
                                                                            1   assignWithCopy for ModifiedContent + 91 (SwiftUI + 3869160) [0x19f2289e8]
                                                                              1   assignWithCopy for ModifiedContent + 91 (SwiftUI + 3869160) [0x19f2289e8]
                                                                                1   assignWithCopy for ModifiedContent + 171 (SwiftUI + 3869240) [0x19f228a38]
                                                                                  1   assignWithCopy for StaticSourceWriter + 71 (SwiftUI + 7810140) [0x19f5eac5c]
                                                                                    1   assignWithCopy for ModifiedContent + 91 (SwiftUI + 3869160) [0x19f2289e8]
                                                                                      1   assignWithCopy for ModifiedContent + 91 (SwiftUI + 3869160) [0x19f2289e8]
                                                                                        1   assignWithCopy for ModifiedContent + 91 (SwiftUI + 3869160) [0x19f2289e8]
                                                                                          1   assignWithCopy for ModifiedContent + 171 (SwiftUI + 3869240) [0x19f228a38]
                                                                                            1   assignWithCopy for _EnvironmentKeyWritingModifier + 131 (SwiftUI + 5064316) [0x19f34c67c]
                                                                                              1   assignWithCopy for ClosedRange<>.Index + 104 (libswiftCore.dylib + 3416420) [0x19c845164]
                                                            1   specialized implicit closure #2 in implicit closure #1 in closure #1 in closure #1 in Attribute.init<A> + 115 (SwiftUI + 875844) [0x19ef4dd44]
                                                              1   LayoutComputer.EngineDelegate.childGeometries + 67 (SwiftUI + 7880644) [0x19f5fbfc4]
                                                                1   _LayoutEngine.childGeometries + 243 (SwiftUI + 7730288) [0x19f5d7470]
                                                                  1   closure #1 in _LayoutEngine.childGeometries + 419 (SwiftUI + 7730964) [0x19f5d7714]
                                                                    1   LayoutProxy.finallyPlaced + 139 (SwiftUI + 3798264) [0x19f2174f8]
                                                                      1   StackLayout.Storage.sizeThatFits + 71 (SwiftUI + 7448628) [0x19f592834]
                                                                        1   StackLayout.UnmanagedImplementation.sizeThatFits + 371 (SwiftUI + 7449012) [0x19f5929b4]
                                                                          1   StackLayout.UnmanagedImplementation.placeChildren + 187 (SwiftUI + 7450556) [0x19f592fbc]
                                                                            1   specialized StackLayout.UnmanagedImplementation.placeChildren1 + 171 (SwiftUI + 7461420) [0x19f595a2c]
                                                                              1   specialized StackLayout.UnmanagedImplementation.sizeChildrenGenerallyWithConcreteMajorProposal + 959 (SwiftUI + 7457184) [0x19f5949a0]
                                                                                1   StackLayout.Storage.explicitAlignment + 31 (SwiftUI + 7449476) [0x19f592b84]
                                                                                  1   StackLayout.UnmanagedImplementation.explicitAlignment + 367 (SwiftUI + 7449856) [0x19f592d00]
                                                                                    1   swift_retain + 76 (libswiftCore.dylib + 3621532) [0x19c87729c]
              1   __CFRunLoopRun + 1527 (CoreFoundation + 634188) [0x19888ad4c]
                1   _CFRelease + 0 (CoreFoundation + 667660) [0x19889300c]
              1   __CFRunLoopRun + 1447 (CoreFoundation + 634108) [0x19888acfc]
                1   _kernelrpc_mach_port_extract_member_trap + 8 (libsystem_kernel.dylib + 17020) [0x1c666827c]
                  1   <Kernel mode>
  3   _pthread_start + 319 (libsystem_pthread.dylib + 6976) [0x1e40e5b40]
    3   _SpeechThread + 47 (TextToSpeechBundleSupport + 117696) [0x1c1b57bc0]
      3   -[TTSSpeechServerInstance _handleSpeechThread] + 2235 (TextToSpeechBundleSupport + 123120) [0x1c1b590f0]
        3   -[ServerSpeechRequest dealloc] + 63 (TextToSpeechBundleSupport + 114212) [0x1c1b56e24]
          3   -[TTSSpeechServerInstance dealloc] + 115 (TextToSpeechBundleSupport + 114616) [0x1c1b56fb8]
            3   CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 599 (CoreFoundation + 631324) [0x19888a21c]
              2   __CFRunLoopRun + 1215 (CoreFoundation + 633876) [0x19888ac14]
                2   __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 380 (CoreFoundation + 658480) [0x198890c30]
                  2   <Effective Thread QoS Unspecified, Requested Thread QoS Unspecified>
              1   __CFRunLoopRun + 1295 (CoreFoundation + 633956) [0x19888ac64]
                1   _pthread_mutex_firstfit_lock_slow + 104 (libsystem_pthread.dylib + 28916) [0x1e40eb0f4]
                  1   <Effective Thread QoS Unspecified, Requested Thread QoS Unspecified>
  3   start_wqthread + 0 (libsystem_pthread.dylib + 42836) [0x1e40ee754]
    2   <Kernel mode, Effective Thread QoS Utility, Requested Thread QoS Utility>
    1   <Kernel mode>
  2   _pthread_wqthread + 331 (libsystem_pthread.dylib + 14396) [0x1e40e783c]
    2   _dispatch_kevent_worker_thread + 975 (libdispatch.dylib + 87368) [0x19851b548]
      1   _dispatch_event_loop_drain_timers + 563 (libdispatch.dylib + 139688) [0x1985281a8]
        1   _dispatch_timer_heap_resift + 548 (libdispatch.dylib + 142000) [0x198528ab0]
      1   _dispatch_event_loop_drain_timers + 275 (libdispatch.dylib + 139400) [0x198528088]
        1   _dispatch_root_queue_poke_slow + 247 (libdispatch.dylib + 66020) [0x1985161e4]
          1   __workq_kernreturn + 0 (libsystem_kernel.dylib + 168316) [0x1c668d17c]
  1   _pthread_wqthread + 275 (libsystem_pthread.dylib + 14340) [0x1e40e7804]
    1   _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 707 (libdispatch.dylib + 89464) [0x19851bd78]
      1   _dispatch_lane_invoke + 407 (libdispatch.dylib + 48220) [0x198511c5c]
        1   _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 579 (libdispatch.dylib + 45324) [0x19851110c]
          1   _dispatch_client_callout + 19 (libdispatch.dylib + 15792) [0x198509db0]
            1   _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 31 (libdispatch.dylib + 8780) [0x19850824c]
              1   ??? (APP NAME + 1950000) [0x102618130]
                1   ??? (APP NAME + 1995076) [0x102623144]
                  1   -[UIApplication _endBackgroundTask:] + 283 (UIKitCore + 12517664) [0x19b2f0120]
                    1   -[_UIBackgroundTaskInfo description] + 87 (UIKitCore + 12327212) [0x19b2c192c]
                      1   -[NSObject description] + 67 (CoreFoundation + 67700) [0x198800874]
                        1   CFStringCreateWithFormat + 47 (CoreFoundation + 816752) [0x1988b7670]
                          1   _CFStringCreateWithFormatAndArgumentsReturningMetadata + 163 (CoreFoundation + 816548) [0x1988b75a4]
                            1   __CFStringAppendFormatCore + 8215 (CoreFoundation + 808924) [0x1988b57dc]
                              1   _platform_memmove + 240 (libsystem_platform.dylib + 22240) [0x1e40e16e0]
                                1   <Effective Thread QoS Default, Requested Thread QoS Default>

  Binary Images:
           0x10243c000 -                ???  com.domain.app 1.18.1 (1.18.1) <5BD8C77A-45E5-3F20-B64B-E49D0B172C10>  /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F738A7F8-37FE-403F-B614-3406087E7B25/APP NAME.app/APP NAME
           0x198506000 -        0x198548fff  libdispatch.dylib                 <0F3905E0-6720-3D08-9AE0-A43A8DA244C0>  /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
           0x198549000 -        0x198583fff  libdyld.dylib                     <785BEE7F-AC2C-388D-865C-36279D1B3DD1>  /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
           0x1987f0000 -        0x198ba9fff  CoreFoundation                    <935533F2-35EE-314E-A760-E74521F68435>  /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
           0x19a700000 -        0x19bbadfff  UIKitCore                         <23311071-8AD7-3E8F-836A-BE5DC8A8B0DF>  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore
           0x19bbd1000 -        0x19be57fff  QuartzCore                        <F911F0C2-D892-355A-B6BA-495376DBF2C7>  /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
           0x19c503000 -        0x19c932fff  libswiftCore.dylib                <11EABDF1-B76A-31D5-9FBF-9B7CE6E2DF00>  /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCore.dylib
           0x19ee78000 -        0x19facdfff  SwiftUI                           <B093A7DA-7111-3E37-AB75-2463CEF8132B>  /System/Library/Frameworks/SwiftUI.framework/SwiftUI
           0x1ad87e000 -        0x1ad8b4fff  libobjc.A.dylib                   <2E47ABD7-2C5A-318D-8044-776883BCCCB6>  /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
           0x1b038b000 -        0x1b0393fff  GraphicsServices                  <08556282-F8E9-3938-A004-0C0EDAC970BD>  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
           0x1bec25000 -        0x1bec27fff  libswiftObjectiveC.dylib          <40B9B3E9-93FF-3884-ADFD-026BB232FB10>  /usr/lib/swift/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib
           0x1c1b3b000 -        0x1c1b7efff  TextToSpeechBundleSupport         <409478F2-9C6C-31A6-B787-30E40A9F8DB1>  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextToSpeech.framework/Frameworks/TextToSpeechBundleSupport.framework/TextToSpeechBundleSupport
           0x1c1bff000 -        0x1c1c2efff  AttributeGraph                    <28A80BBA-5743-325B-8029-0671986D9E4A>  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AttributeGraph.framework/AttributeGraph
           0x1c6664000 -        0x1c6695fff  libsystem_kernel.dylib            <95C83DA7-B2CA-3C43-BA7F-7088C04DE757>  /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
           0x1e4079000 -        0x1e407afff  libsystem_blocks.dylib            <460D7D6F-783A-3E58-8E34-DEC38EAE1938>  /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
           0x1e40dc000 -        0x1e40e2fff  libsystem_platform.dylib          <AD029366-1E30-32CD-8E4C-A025B49E513B>  /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
           0x1e40e4000 -        0x1e40effff  libsystem_pthread.dylib           <85AA620C-0B54-3F75-B11F-0D45CDD71628>  /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
```

Comment: Your app has exceeded its "wakeups" quota. Some more information [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/124180) you might find that the time profile or system trace instruments will help, but you possibly have some sort of race condition that is repeatedly blocking and unblocking a thread.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25848441/app-shutdown-with-exc-resource-wakeups-exception-on-ios-8-gm

Comment: @Paulw11 cool, I had no idea about this.